Error when trying to intialize Tesseract4Android
I'm developing an Android application and I need OCR for it, so I decided to use Tesseract4Android. When I start the app I get the following error:

Could not initialize Tesseract API with language=eng!

I am using version 4.7.0:
implementation("cz.adaptech.tesseract4android:tesseract4android-openmp:4.7.0")

My tessdata directory is located on the device's external memory: "External storage/tessdata/tessdata". In the second tessdata directory I have the file bul.traineddata eng.traineddata and tessdata_config.json. The latter contains this:
{
  "files": [
    "eng.traineddata",
    "bul.traineddata"
  ]
}

I downloaded the .traineddata files from here. This is the code of the class I use:
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Environment
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI
import java.io.File

class OcrHelper(private val context: Context) {

    private var tess: TessBaseAPI = TessBaseAPI()

    init {
        val dataPath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/tessdata").absolutePath
        tess.init(dataPath, "eng")
    }

    fun extractTextFromImage(bitmap: Bitmap): String {
        tess.setImage(bitmap)
        val text = tess.utF8Text
        tess.recycle()
        return text
    }
}

And this is the code for my main activity:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var b: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var ocrHelper: OcrHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        b = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(b.root)

        ocrHelper = OcrHelper(this)

        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.my_image)
        val extractedText = ocrHelper.extractTextFromImage(bitmap)
        b.textView.text = extractedText
    }
}


tess-two doesn't seem to be developed anymore: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/tags, I might suspect there will be some incompatibilities with newer Tesseract and Android versions. Did you have a specific reason why you chose that library? There are newer ones out there that I would suspect to work better nowadays. The first one I just stumbled upon looks promising at first glance: https://github.com/adaptech-cz/Tesseract4Android -- but there may be better ones out there, I haven't actually did a proper research.

@Leviathan Thanks for the reply. Tried doing it with Tesseract4Android, but I keep getting the same error. Actually, the things that I changed were settings.gradle.kts (`dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
    maven { url = URL("https://jitpack.io").toURI() }
}

}) and build.gradle.kts :app (implementation ("cz.adaptech.tesseract4android:tesseract4android-openmp:4.7.0")`)

So, is your question now about Tesseract4Android instead of tess-two? Please update the question to be explicit about what you have so far and what you want to achieve.

I have updated the question but my problem is still the same - error initializing the tesseract api on eng language. I tried with another language but again it doesn't work.
